# Rails 3.2 Carrierwave precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, carrierwave, pre-compilation

I got a `class AvatarUploader < Carrierwave::Uploader::Base` which store `User` avatars in `public/uploads` dir:

```rails
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :main do
     process :resize_to_limit => [128, 128]
  end
```

And I want to start application in `production` mode with assets precompilation enabled. Everything but avatars work fine. When I visit any `User` profile I get:

```rails
Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-03 17:45:24 +0300
Processing by Users::UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Rendered users/users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms

ActionView::Template::Error ( isn't precompiled):
    87:                     <%= image_tag @user.avatar_url(:main).to_s %>
  app/views/users/users/show.html.erb:87:in `_app_views_users_users_show_html_erb___538221278131396366_28399560'
```

Maybe there is a way to turn off precompilation for avatars(because they could be re-uploaded when app is running on production). Please provide any suggestions how to fix this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When image_tag receives a blank string, it tries to get a resource
>   from the asset pipeline and returns
>
> "isn't precompiled"

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3080

Print `@user.avatar_url(:main).to_s` to double check

Comment: I check the url and it is blank( Now I will look for a solution. Thank you for a help!